# What is a good Linux friendly desktop wireless card?

Tags: linux, hardware-rec, compatibility

And that would mean one that works with little to no finagling, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something based on an Atheros AR24XX (`ath5k` module). They're found in several cards; take a look around.

Answer (score 2):

RaLink chip based wifi cards are known to be Linux friendly. I have one at home, installation is really 5 minutes (plug-in, let system install what it wants, copy firmware file to specified folder). If you have a wired Internet access, all modern Linux distributions will probably automatically download the firmware, too.

Answer (score 0):

Anything by intel or atheros is usually good for wireless. Avoid broadcom like the plague, though their physical wire ethernet adapators work. Just not their wireless.

Comment: Intel doesn't make wireless desktop cards, so you'll need a PCI or PCI Express adapter in order to use them.